# pigpio's sending only partial and inaccurate data

Tags: pi-zero-w, sensor, pigpio, lirc

I want to send IR signals with pigpio and receive it, all on a raspberry zero w. To send the data, I use the IR Record and Playback script from the [pigpio library](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py). To receive data, I use the code from [this tutorial](https://blog.bschwind.com/2016/05/29/sending-infrared-commands-from-a-raspberry-pi-without-lirc/)
I cannot use LIRC because I want to have two separate receivers and this is easier to achieve with the above method.
when I send the following signal, almost arbitrary values are received. the led is aimed directly towards the receiver

This is what I send:

```
[875, 875, 875, 875, 875, 112, 550, 112, 550, 112, 344, 112, 344, 112, 550, 112, 344, 112, 550, 875, 875, 875, 875, 875]
```

And these are 3 samples of what was received.

```
855 816 1579 79 3327 1445 257 827 951

912 816 2700 215 1354 83 2335 824 920

734 826 918 824 4962 804 925 821 917
```

not only was it only partially received, it is also not accurate at all.

What I have tried as well is to send data with LIRC. But it is also sent very unaccurately.
I know that it's the sender that is not accurate, because when I point a tv remote at the receiver, all the incoming signal samples are almost identical.

what could be wrong?

Comment: You need to explain how you are sending and how you are receiving.  I can see no correlation between what you send and receive.

Comment: Thank you joan. In the second sentence of the question I explain how I send and receive. Should I post the code from the tutorial here for you?

Comment: piscope will show you what pigpio is transmitting.  I am only interested if that shows pigpio is not transmitting what you sent.

Comment: I have found the answer, to the problem. I don't know the reason of the problem but I found it. I will write the answer when I have time and if you are interested. Many thanks for your efforts and time joan!

Comment: Certainly answer your own question, especially if you think the answer will help others.